# Would nearest point using Geodesic distance and nearest point using Haversine distance be the same point?

Tags: python, distance, proximity, geodesic, haversine

I have a point A and trying to find the nearest point to A in a list of points (B, C, D).

I could use knn with `haversine` metrics and get the nearest point like this:

```
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric='haversine')

knn.fit(df['lat', 'lon']) 

dist, idx = knn.kneighbors([(35.9157825, -79.0826045)])
```

However, I'm not sure if this point `df.loc[idx]` will always be the same point i'd get if I calculate distance using geodesic?

knn is very fast compared to having to calculate geodesic distance for all the points in my list. So I would love to use knn if the nearest point would always be the same.

Comment: It should only be different if the geodesic function is pulling from a specified datum... though I am not an expert in this.

Comment: "Always" seems like an impossibly high bar; surely you can design a test case where this fails.  Whether this test case is significant with your data is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure, "closest" will return *different* points, in general, for
great-circle (what you call haversine) and geodesic distances.  For a
specific example, consider the set of points {A, B} where the positions
(lat, lon) are: A = (10.03°, 0°); B = (0°, 10°).  The
point P = (0°, 0°) is closest to B according to the great-circle
distance, but is closest to A according to the geodesic distance (for the WGS84 ellipsoid).

[GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io) (written by me)
offers a
[NearestNeighbor](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/classGeographicLib_1_1NearestNeighbor.html#details)
class which implements a
[vantage-point tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantage-point_tree),
which is an efficient method of finding the nearest neighbor in any
metric space.  (Geodesic distance defines a metric space.)  There's a python implementation of vantage-point
trees available [here](https://github.com/RickardSjogren/vptree).