# What are geodesic distance calculations used In ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, geodesic

I'm working on a project where I need to calculate geodesic distances for millions of lat-long points.

Just out of curiousity and in a search for better methods of geodesic distance calculation, I'm wondering, what does ArcGIS use for geodesic distances?

I haven't seem to have found much of any information on that. Also, at the moment I'm using Vincenty's formula (instead of Haversine/Great circle) in Python.

Comment: I believe, if you compare your Vincenty code with the output of the Direct and Inverse functions in ArcPy, you'll find them in very close agreement (provided you use both correctly), certainly within the precision provided by the SpatialReference being used.

Comment: If you want to find the closest point in a large collection of points, then you can save a lot of time by organizing the collection into a vantage point tree.  After you set up the tree, a query takes log(N) distance calculations vs N such calculations.  See my answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349257/would-nearest-point-using-geodesic-distance-and-nearest-point-using-haversine-di/351047#351047 for some relevant links.